# duplicating the same method with const?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

In  C++, I see this code.

```
public: 
    Ports& GetPorts();
    const Ports& GetPorts() const;
```

Why is it necessary to have another method with const? 
How can a compiler decide which method is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `x.GetPorts()` and `x` is a non-`const` object, the first version will be called.  If `x` is a `const` object, on the other hand, the second version will be called.  That kind of code is saying "if the object is modifiable, allow the result of `GetPorts()` to be modified; if the object is `const`, don't allow the result to be modified."  The compiler will prefer the first version if it matches; however, it will not be present if the object is `const` and so the second version will be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

Because the first overload is not a const method you can't call it over temporaries and const objects. If you provide a const overload you essentially support const objects.

The compiler will use the const overload for const objects and the none-const overload for none-const objects.

It is usually not necessary to provide an overload if your function is const, because const functions are as safe as they get: they work for both const objects and none-const objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is necessary only if you want to have different behavior for const and non-const objects. Otherwise the second version is enough. A design decision.

Comment: The behavior may be identical. Normally these functions only differ in having a different return type.

Comment: @UncleBens: Sure, if they return different things, they are different. Then you need two of them, otherwise not. If you don't return a modifiable reference to class members, you avoid a lot of this,